# Get Joomla Banner Description in the module

Tags: joomla

Hi I want to modify the default joomla banner module so instead of displaying only banner image it also displays description text that has been entered in the backend. 
Can you help me? Thanks[image: banner component joomla backend]

Comment: are you using Joomla default `mod_banner`?

Comment: @Tomado yes I tried to echo $item->description but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using default `mod_banner` of `Joomla`, you need to add some changes in it to show your description in the module where you want to show it.

1. You need to go to the front-end component, `models` of `com_banners` for `banners.php`.Navigation for it is `components\com_banners\models\banners.php` in this file on  the `getListQuery` you need to add the following line of code in the `'a.description as description,'.` in `$query->select` like others. That's it for this file.
2. Now go to your `modules\mod_banners\tmpl\default.php` and access that variable description as you tried `echo $item->description`.

**Or**

If you don't want to change your core files then you need to do it with **Template override** the output from the Joomla! core.

For more details go to that link [How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Comment: Ah .. Do you have other solution that only need to modify the default.php?  I expect to not edit core things like the models :(

Comment: ok thanks tornado. I indeed want to override it from template side, but you can't override models files. Only view's files can be overrided. But it's ok, I've managed to find other solution. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @dreamexploded Yapp you can only override the html file with template overridden.Suggestion: You can directly fetch the data to the html file.

Comment: why the hell do they have a description option if they don't provide it. I swear joomla is garbage sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

This post is old but here is the answer:

```
<?php 
     /** Description from the Banner  **/
     $db = &JFactory::getDBO();
         $bid = $item->id;
         $sql = "SELECT `description` FROM `rlz1b_banners` WHERE '$bid'"; 
                 /*rlz1b_banners is your database name*/
         $db->setQuery($sql);
         $db->query();
         $res = $db->loadAssocList(); 
?>
<p><?php  echo $res[0][description]; ?></p>
```

This is Excelent for SEO frendly Banners in Joomla 2.5.

Comment: Works great in Joomla 3.6 too. Thank you!